# Why Lambda expression returns System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2 as a result

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, collections

I'm getting following string as result while returning a list of string using lambda expression:

> System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[HOrg.ServiceCatalog.Contracts.Models.IOfferProperty,System.String]

My code is:

```
    IList<string> offerIds = new List<string>();
    foreach (var offer in offerProperties)
    {
       offerIds.Add(offer
         .Where(x => x.PropertyDefinitionId == propertyDefinitionId)
         .Select(x => x.OfferId)
         .ToString());
    }
```

Within foreach loop, offer variable contains expected values. But when I make condition using lambda expression, it returns **System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2** as a result.

When I search for this, I got a few suggestions like,

1. Copying results of lambda expressions in to a seperate list
2. Use `ToList()` for lambda expression then assign it to a result variable

and more suggestion. But no answer is helpful for me.

Is anybody know what's wrong in this code?

Comment: `Join` all the items of the sequence: `string.Join("; ", offer.Where. ... .Select(x => x.OfferId))`

Comment: You should realise that that's the *default* result of calling `ToString` on a type that hasn't overridden the one from `Object`. Which means it's almost certainly *not* meant to have `ToString()` called on it outside of debug scenarios..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *converting* sequence to `String`:

```
 // How can .Net convert sequence into string? The only way is to return type name
 // which is unreadable System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEn... 
 offer
   .Where(x => x.PropertyDefinitionId == propertyDefinitionId)
   .Select(x => x.OfferId)
   .ToString()
```

`Join` the items into a `string`

```
  // Join items into string with "; " delimiter, e.g. "1; 2; 3; 4"
  offerIds.Add(string.Join("; ", offer
    .Where(x => x.PropertyDefinitionId == propertyDefinitionId)
    .Select(x => x.OfferId)));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you expect a single result for every offer, try:

```
IList<string> offerIds = new List<string>();
foreach (var offer in offerProperties)
{
   offerIds.Add(offer.Where(x => x.PropertyDefinitionId == propertyDefinitionId).Select(x => x.OfferId).FirstOrDefault()?.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Would be better to suggest: `offer.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PropertyDefinitionId == propertyDefinitionId)?.OfferId.ToString()`

Comment: I have tried what you suggest. Even all the valid records also returning null.

Comment: @novicedeveloper - we don't have access to your code or your data. Nobody can provide you a *tested* working solution unless you give us more information. A good start would be a [mcve] and a clear description of what the code is *meant* to be achieving

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you want a collection of offerIds as a string, where multiple are attached to the offerproperties.

If so, then you are looking for the addrange function. Also move your `ToString()` call inside the select statement, not after it.

```
IList<string> offerIds = new List<string>();
foreach (var offer in offerProperties)
{
    offerIds.AddRange(offer.Where(x => x.PropertyDefinitionId == propertyDefinitionId).Select(x => x.OfferId.ToString()));
}
```

Now for each offer, a selection of OfferId-strings is added to your offerIds IList